# How can I display images in terminal from a filename?

Tags: command-line, 18.04

I use Ubuntu 18.04 and want to display images in terminal from a specified file name.I tried VIU and FIM, but they display the image in different windows. I want the image to displayed in the same window under some text.How can I do so?